# tag users with @ and department with # tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am Creating a tagging system . And all-most dome . But right now a problem occurred .actually i want

1. when a user enter @ then a dropdown list will display same like
       facebook .
2. also there is departments . when user enter # the department list
   will display

i have done the first part . below is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
var start2 = /@/ig; // @ Match
    var word2 = /@(\w+)/ig; //@abc Match

    $(document).on("keyup", "#mention-text", function() {
        var content2 = $(this).html(); //Content Box Data
        var go = content2.match(start2); //Content Matching @
        var name = content2.match(word2); //Content Matching @abc
        var dataString = 'searchword=' + name;
        //If @ available
        if (go.length > 0) {
            $("#msgbox-dept").slideDown('show');
            $("#display-dept").slideUp('show');
            $("#msgbox-dept").html("Type the name of someone or something...");
            //if @abc avalable
            if (name.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: base_url + '/notes/getusersdept', // Database name search 
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#msgbox-dept").hide();
                        $("#display-dept").html(data).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    //Adding result name to content box.
    $(document).on("click", ".addname2", function() {
        var username2 = $(this).attr('title');
        var old2 = $("#mention-text").html();
        var content2 = old2.replace(word2, " "); //replacing @abc to (" ") space
        $("#mention-text").html(content2);
        var E2 = "&nbsp<a class='red mentions' contenteditable='false' href='#' >" + username2 + "</a>&nbsp; ";
        $("#mention-text").append(E2);
        $("#mention-text br").remove();
        $("#display-dept").hide();
        $("#msgbox-dept").hide();
    });
})
```

working properly for @ but i want it for @ and #. I also tried regex

```
var start2 = /@|#/ig; // @ Match
var word2 = /@|#(\w+)/ig; //@abc Match
```

but no luck till now . any help will appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:@|#)(\w+)\b
```

You can try this to match both.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/34

Comment: thankx for the reply.i want to send rwquest to different url . with @ - getusers with # -get departments. is it possible??

Comment: You can simply then check for `^@` and `^#` .whichever passes you can take the suitable action

Comment: can you please show me . I am not much familiar with jquery .

Comment: @ris dunno much about jquery but you can appy that regex.`^@.*` if it fails you can try `^#.*`.Based on the regex which passed you can send post request to that url